# Understanding the proof of ${\rm ord}(G)=p^n \Rightarrow Z(G) \neq \{e\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ be a group. I have some troubles to understand the proof of ${\rm ord}(G)=p^n \Rightarrow Z(G) \neq \{e\}$. The proof is given as follow:

Observe the Group $G$ acting on itself by conjugation, then we have:

$$x \in Z(G) \iff Z_G(\{x\})=G \iff (G:Z_G(\{x\}))=1$$

Until here it is okay, but now it goes on with:
So $$x \neq Z(G) \Rightarrow p\, \mid \frac{{\rm ord}(G)}{{\rm ord}(Z_G(\{x\}))}.$$

Why we get this inclusion? The last is because of the lagrange theorem but why we take $x \neq Z(G)$?

Many thanks for some help.

Comment: It should be $x\notin Z(G)$, and it follows from the class formula. Note that all distinct orbits of a group action on a set forms a partition of that set

Comment: can you please give some details? I still don't see it

Comment: Your first chain of implications is false.  $Z_G(x)=G\iff x\in Z(G)$.

Comment: Note that $Z_G(\{x\})$, which presumably means the centralizer, is usually denoted by $C_G(\{x\})$ or $C_G(x)$, rather than $Z_G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the class formula, $|G|=|Z(G)|+\sum_i [G:Z_G(x_i)]$. If $x\in G\setminus Z(G)$, its centralizer $Z_G(x)$ is a subgroup of $G$, so it has order $p^k$. So $[G:Z_G(x_i)]=p^{n-k}$, and thus if $|Z(G)|=1, |G|\equiv 1\pmod{p}$, a contradiction. Hence $Z(G)$ is a nontrivial p-subgroup of $G$.

Comment: We don't have that for all $x \in G$, $Z_G(x)$ is a subgroup of $G$?

Comment: @FrederickManfred It is straightforward to check by definition. In particular if x is in the center of G, it commutes with every element of G, i.e. $Z_G(x)=G$.